# Length between to moving points

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, related-rates

Point A moves along the x-axis at the constant rate of a ft/s while point B moves along the y-axis at the constant rate of b ft/s. Find how fast the distance between them is changing when A is at the point $(x,0)$ and B is at the point $(0,y)$.

I found this question in a textbook on Calculus and Analytic Geometry. I approached it very mechanically: the known constants are $dx\over dt$$= a$ and $dy \over dt$$= b$. The length between the two points can be found from $(x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}$. Call this length function $l$. Know, I found the derivative of this length function to be $ax + by \over l$ which doesn't seem to be constant. What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you think that the rate at which the distance between the points is changing should be constant?

Comment: Is it not? I didn't think the book would require to find it of it wasn't.

Comment: Your question does not entirely make sense. Isn't the relation $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ not linear (enough evidence).

Comment: @Camelot823 The problem specifically asks for the rate of change when $A=(x,0)$ and $B=(0,y)$. If the rate of change was constant, there would have been no need to specify at what points.

Comment: Hi there. I'm curious why you have accepted only 1 out of 47 answers to your previous questions? $\quad$ In any case, do consider that users who [accept ✔ good answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) to their past questions are more likely to have their future questions answered.

Comment: @ryang how do I accept an answer? I haven't been informed of this knowledge earlier.

Comment: @ryang ahh... My apologies; I've only now realised the checkmark. Thank you.

Comment: @Camelot823 No problem. I hope, when you have time, you will go back and accept the deserving old answers. This helps the site function better, as it signals resolution, prevents the page from being bumped, scores points, and influences the site's search results, cleanup activities, and other behind-the-scenes processes.